# Simple Javascript doesn't work in FireFox (but does in ALL other Browsers)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, hidden

I have this code which I'm using to reveal the Answers to some questions in an FAQ section on my website. You click the question and the div containing the answer is revealed below.

It works in Safari, Chrome, Opera and even IE, but not in Firefox.

The links just do nothing.

Any ideas why, or any better methods for doing an 'FAQ' section? I have already got jQuery loaded in my page if there's something that could be done better with it there, I don't know. Or a CSS only solution?

Here is my code:

**JS code:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(tag) {
        if (tag.style.display=='') {
            tag.style.display='none'    
        } else {
            tag.style.display=''
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="javascript: toggle(question1)">FAQ Question goes here</a>
    <div id="question1" style="display:none">
        <p>FAQ Answer goes here</p>
    </div
```

Comment: What is your FF version? Your code works just fine for me in FF 3.6.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, I recommend you use jquery, you will not have this kind of problem and it's less than 30 Kbs.

Here is what you look for:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Anyway, you should always use: `document.getElementByID` to get a certain element.

**EDITED**

It depends on the structure of your HTML, if I had this situation:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/Qcm4G/

I would do this:

```
$(".questionsheader").click(function(){
                             $(this).next("div").toggle();                             }
);
```

**SOME OTHER CONSIDERATIONS**

- I wouldn't use "display:none" for the answers for a simple yet perhaps not practical reason. People without javascript enabled (as happen with the software of some handicapped people) will not be able to read the answers. This is why I hide the answers with javascript. They will only disappear if javascript is enabled.
- You can use other effects like animate(), slidetoggle() to make it more interesting.

Comment: $('.target').toggle(); - seems to just target one element / one question

Comment: @netadictos - please see the comments I posted in your JS fiddle link. or read them  here: Hi mate,
Thanks so much for this - it works a treat and looks alot cleaner and more semantic than what I had before, youve cut the amount of JS down to less than 1/4 of what I was using before.

Only thing is though.. you have the display:none CSS inside the DIV tag. Should'nt this be kept seperate in the style-sheet?

I have moved it to the stylesheet and styled the .question class as display:none.

Comment: All works well like this, except when JS is turned off the Answers are still not visible. Is that why you put the display:none styling inside the DIV?

Comment: @Phil- sorry that was a cut-paste mistake. I didn't realize about the inline style. I have suppressed it. You can look at the jsfiddle example again. Thx. It must work without js active.

Answer (score 4):

Because you set the ID of the element you want to toggle, you would need to use:

```
document.getElementByID(tag).style.display
```

instead of just `tag.style.display` inside of your toggle function.

Answer (score 3):

try setting your display to 'block'

```
tag.style.display='block'
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to do this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggle(tag) {
      tag.style.display = (tag.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok there are a number of issues in your code

First, it is important to end your lines with a semi-colon.

`tag.style.display='none'` should be  `tag.style.display='none';`

Second, You must use document.getElementById on the id to get the DOM Element

I would do somthing like this:

```
function toggle(elementId) {
    var tag = document.getElementById(elementId);
    ...
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/abuce4/edit) http://jsbin.com/abuce4/edit

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have jQuery, try this:

```
$("#" + tag).toggle();
```

Comment: wouldn't that just show one answer though? I have about 25 questions in my FAQ list so each question's link would need to trigger its answer

Comment: Sorry im not great with jQ.. how could i implement this solution/idea?

Answer (score 1):

try `<a onclick='toggle(document.getElementById("question1"));'">`

Comment: I dont think its valid XHTML to use onclick inside anchors is it?

Comment: want to try and do this sematically if possible

Comment: `onclick` is actually better than `javascript:` URIs, since if the user middle-clicks on something with `onclick` it will still open in a new window instead of opening a blank window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (quotes added):

```
<a href="javascript: toggle('question1')">FAQ Question goes here</a>
    <div id="question1" style="display:none">
        <p>FAQ Answer goes here</p>
    </div>
```

and (used getElementById):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(tag) {
    tag = document.getElementById(tag);
    if (tag.style.display=='') {
        tag.style.display='none'    
    } else {
        tag.style.display=''
    }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATES**: for the jQuery solution, I would use the jQuery Tabs approach:

```
<a class="toggle" href="#question1">FAQ Question Link 1</a>
<div id="question1" style="display:none">
    <p>FAQ Answer goes here</p>
</div>
<a class="toggle" href="#question2">FAQ Question Link 2</a>
<div id="question2" style="display:none">
    <p>FAQ Answer goes here</p>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ifaour - that does work! I think im going to hold out, or try for a jQuery solution though (unless you have one of those too?) If nothing comes up ill award you the 'answer' though. Thank you

Comment: well for the jQuery solution, I would use the jQuery Tabs approach, check my updates

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(this).next().toggle();">Question</a>
<div style="display:none;">Answer</div>
```

Or more 'generic' and clean :

HTML :

```
<a class="question">Question 1</a>
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

<a class="question">Question 2</a>
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
```

CSS :

```
.answer{
display:none;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".question").click(function(event){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
}
```

slideToggle(); or toggle();
Enjoy.